# How to correct, "copying: Failed /media/user/path/KorganizerArchive.ics"?

Tags: permissions, korganizer

I receive this notification several times each day now. I set up Korganizer to automatically archive events older than 30 days.  The path and file are the designated place to archive the events. This file was last modified on 14 October 2017, about 3 weeks ago. I can open the file. It is 706.6 KiB. User has ownership of the folder it is in with Read/Modify permission. User has ownership of the file with Read/Write permissions. The disk is not full. I can export a calendar to that directory.  I can restore the archive.ics file as a new calendar. I can no longer manually or automatically archive events from korganizer.

Comment: I don't know - but did you check media contains free inodes?  ie. `df -hi`  (disk free, human output, inodes)

Comment: @chrisguiver I have low IUse every where:  

Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on  
/dev/sda6        1.3M   38K  1.2M    4% /media/geoffrey/MyDocs  

  I never heard of Inodes before (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1041694).

Comment: Type `mount | grep /media/user/path` - `ro` means "read-only", `rw` means "read/write"

Comment: @waltinator I've tried studying up on mount and grep but I'm not sure what this command is supposed to do or show.  I think that grep needs a search argument.  Am I supposed to search for "ro"   I'm new to ubuntu command line and need a little more direction please.  Thank you!

Comment: Read `man mount`. Read `man grep`. Read `man bash` to understand the pipe "`|`" which connects STDOUT of the left side to STDIN of the right side.

Comment: @waltinator OK, plain `mount` basically gives a list of mounted devices (with their attributes) plus some other stuff.  `grep` takes that list as the list of places to search for KorganizerArchive.ics  I don't understand yet how `-ro` and `-rw` modify the `grep` command.  They are listed as switches for `mount`. But I thought the `mount` command is completed before the  pipe|    `mount | grep /media/geoffrey/MyDocs/ZEEP/KorganizerArchive.ics -ro` and `mount | grep /media/geoffrey/MyDocs/ZEEP/KorganizerArchive.ics -rw` give different filename results.  `-ro` lists some _.xsession-errors:_

Comment: My mistake! `ro` and `rw` are atoms to look for in the `mount` output. My bad formatting in comments. I should have said: 
 
Type `mount | grep /media/user/path`. In the output from `mount`, `ro` means "read only", `rw` means "read write".

Comment: @waltinator So, we're just checking to see if this device is mounted -rw.  If it were mounted -ro, that would be the reason the copy failed.  It is mounted -rw    What next?  Is this a bug in Kontact? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Check the permissions, ownership, mount status if appropriate, on each directory from `/` to `/media/user/path`. My `pathlld` script does this, https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: Pretty nifty Bash script @waltinator, thank you.  A couple of the directories belong to _root_ and not to _user_. The file belongs to _user_ and is rwxrwxrwc. I opened, edited and saved a text file in the same directory. Would I be correct in thinking that this indicates that the source of the  _copying:failed_ error is not with the destination file.

Comment: "`rwxrwxrwc`"? Are you sure that isn't a typ[o?

Comment: Yup, my typo, sorry. Its  `-rwxrwxrwx 1 geoffrey geoffrey`

Comment: Don't retype (with errors) - rather, cut-and-paste. Your ability to create a file in a particular directory depends on the protection **of the directory**. What is the protection of `/media/user/path`, and is `/media/user` mounted read only (`ro`)?.  No, the cause of _copying:failed_ is probably with the destination directory or mounts.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, I'll be more disciplined with cutting and pasting code from now on.   `/media/user/path` has permissions like this: `drwxrwxrwx 1 geoffrey geoffrey` And  `/media/user` is mounted like this `/dev/sda6 on /media/user type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)`  I edited my question to include successful tests of writing to the directory. Maybe this is a Korganizer bug or a file corruption.   From my edited question, do you still think it could be a permission question?